# Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index (mentioned code)

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

```
ConvertingColumn[] ccsColumns = new ConvertingColumn[iConvertingColumnCount];
ArrayList[] arrConvertingColumn = new ArrayList[2];
arrConvertingColumn[0] = GetConvertingColumns(toResult, arrCorrPK, arrFirstLevelSplitColumn, arrFirstLevelCorrelationColumn, arrDataColumn);
arrConvertingColumn[1] = GetConvertingColumns(toResult, null, arrSecondLevelSplitColumn, arrSecondLevelCorrelationColumn, null);

int iCounter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for (int j = 0; j <= arrConvertingColumn[i].Count; j++)
   {
       ccsColumns[iCounter] = (ConvertingColumn)arrConvertingColumn[i][j];
       iCounter++;
   }
}
```

please help me.

Comment: `arrConvertingColumn` is defined as an array with 2 elements, yet you loop over `i <= 3`

Comment: Magic numbers are bad. What is the `3` in the outer for loop supposed to be? If you meant for it to be the length/count of items in the `ArrayList` (are you sure you can't use anything more typesafe than an `ArrayList`?), then why don't you use that respective property? --- Sorry, the ArrayList array.

Answer (score 2):

`arrConvertingColumn` is an array with size 2 since you have initialized it in this way:

```
ArrayList[] arrConvertingColumn = new ArrayList[2];
```

so you can access index 0 and 1 (arrays are zero based), but you cannot access index 2 and 3. But that are you trying if you loop until 3.

You can loop it until 1, so change:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
    // ...
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
{
    // ...
```

Since the object in the `ArrayList` also seems to be an array use `< Count` instead of `<= Count`(again, arrays are zero based):

```
// ...
for (int j = 0; j < arrConvertingColumn[i].Count; j++)
{
    // ....
```

By the way, you should use a strongly typed `ConvertingColumn[]` instead of an `ArrayList`.

Comment: hi tim,thanks for your help,i changed to 1 in for loop still am getting same

Comment: @KrishKumar: have a look at my edit. Use `j < arrConvertingColumn[i].Count`